# Exit opened Application

Tags: c#

I'd like to know how to exit my opened Application properly.
The way I am currently trying is not working.

This is how I am opening the application:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (status != true)
    {
        status = true;

        // Start a process to print a file and raise an event when done.
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\Test\\Test.exe";
        myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(Process_Exited);
        myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        myProcess.Start();
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myProcess.Close();
    status = false;
}
```

Comment: What API are you using? WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET? How are you “currently trying” and what makes you think it “is not working”?

Comment: I've answered my question already below, the problem is solved.

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to do it, just do:

```
myProcess.Kill();
```

Comment: Note, this is not like exiting the program. Doing kill is like doing a "end task" from task manager on your program.

Comment: The Application.Exit will allow the OnClosing events to fire and message all windows with a close event. In most cases, it will be a cleaner way to close the application. Killing the process will force the application to close even if a document is unsaved, prompts or not. A hard close or a soft close can be used, generally with different needs.